# JOOQ DAO using Transaction support

Tags: database, transactions, jooq, hikaricp, ratpack

Iam using JOOQ/Hikari to perform DB operations on Postgres. I have been trying to look at some examples of using Transactional operations using JOOQ on generated DAOs. Most of my colleagues use Spring Transactions but I am using Guice for DI so do not want to bring spring into  picture. Any links or ideas are greatly appreciated? If that matters, my App  is built on Ratpack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOOQ  also supports transaction from 3.6 
This is based on JDBC transaction.

Although transaction is not possible from generated DAOs,  it is possible to use it at the DSLContext level(lower level APIs to interact with DB)

Here is the documentation.
https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.6/manual/sql-execution/transaction-management/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ratpack I recommend looking at https://github.com/ratpack/ratpack/blob/master/ratpack-jdbc-tx/src/main/java/ratpack/jdbctx/Transaction.java

Comment: Thank you. we are not using 1.5. I am looking for JOOQ support.

Comment: That will work for jooq too when you are able to upgrade